# Preloading Scripts and other files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built a website which use a lot of different scripts and files, for plugins etc.

I am thinking of how I can make the loading process of these scripts.

I want to load all files and script after a login page, at first with a kind of status-bar ("files are loading....x %").

The idea is to load all files and make the page faster, because the files comes from the cache.

What's your opinion and which is the best way to do it?

Until now, I have include all files with the classical way (link, script, img etc)

Comment: you can consider bundling

Comment: You can also use sites like http://www.shrinker.ch/ to shrink all your JS files into 1 and then include single JS file. Same can be done for CSS as well.

Comment: Note that questions asking for opinions are specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow. See [ask] and the [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think its convenient to do this that you are saying... to load all files after login instance, except that all those files are going to always be used on all web site pages.-

I think a most convenient strategy would be a load on demand strategy ....

An example of load on demand would be to test at runtime whether or not certain browser capabilities and if not then bring them by loading on execution time a specific .js (polyfills).

If the browser has this capability then don't load the .js.-

See [Modernizr.js](https://modernizr.com/) a [Paul Irish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Irish) js library to test browser capabilities at execution time.-

Here [another reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809450/conditionally-load-polyfills) explainning how to conditionally load a pollyfills.-